# 'rest_framework_nested.routers' error in Docker only

Tags: python, django, docker, django-rest-framework, debian

I am trying to deploy a Django app through docker but am stumped at this problem.  When I run my application locally, I have no problems but when I deploy to Docker I get this error:

`AttributeError: module 'rest_framework_nested.routers' has no attribute 'NestedDefaultRouter'`

The last lines of the stack trace looks like this:

```
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/= /app/store/urls.py", line 13, in <module>
    modules_router = routers.NestedDefaultRouter(router, 'modules', lookup='module')
AttributeError: module 'rest_framework_nested.routers' has no attribute 'NestedDefaultRouter'
```

The file where the error emanates from looks like this:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
from rest_framework_nested import routers
from . import views

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('modules', views.ModuleViewSet, basename='modules')

modules_router = routers.NestedDefaultRouter(router, 'modules', lookup='module')
```

My Dockerfile looks as follows:

```
FROM python:3.9.9-slim

#Set up user
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install sudo
RUN addgroup app && adduser -system app -ingroup app
USER app
WORKDIR = /app

#Environment settings`
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

#Install MySQL and dependencies
RUN sudo apt-get -y install python3.9-dev
RUN sudo apt-get -y install default-libmysqlclient-dev
RUN sudo apt-get -y install build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev
RUN sudo apt-get -y install libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev zlib1g-dev
RUN pip install mysqlclient
RUN sudo apt-get -y install default-mysql-server
RUN sudo apt-get -y install gunicorn3

#Copy files and install other dependencies
COPY . .
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

I have been trawling the web for hours without luck.  Seems to be a bit of an anomaly unless I am missing something very obvious.

Running the same code base same settings file etc. locally goes without issue.  And, yes, `drf-nested-routers==0.93.4` is in the requirements file.  When I run `pip3 install drf-nested-routers` in the docker environment I get that the requirement is already satisfied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to track down this issue.

`NestedDefaultRouter` is a method in `rest_framework_nested` that comes with installing the `drf-nested-routers` package.  For some reason I also had the `django-rest-framework-nested` package installed.  This appears to have been the problem.  After uninstalling `django-rest-framework-nested` the image starts up without issues.

The fact that it worked locally and not in Docker is likely due an order of installation issue.  Anyways, fixed now.